# concatenation occurs besides sum

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to build a calculator but in that i am unable to perform sum operation besides it concatenation is occurred how i can do this sum, also how to empty the text box when entering new value in the text-box after pressing '=' my code is this

```
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <script>
    var v = 0 ;
    var operator = '';
    function calc(obj){

    if (obj.value == '+' || obj.value == '-' || obj.value == '*' || obj.value == '/'  ){
     v = document.getElementById("text_field").value;
     operator = obj.value;
        document.getElementById("text_field").value = '';

        }
else if (obj.value == '='){

            if (operator == '+')
        {
        document.getElementById("text_field"). value = v + document.getElementById("text_field").value  ;

        }   
        if (operator == '-')
        {
        document.getElementById("text_field").value = v - document.getElementById("text_field").value  ;

        }   
        if (operator == '*')
        {
        document.getElementById("text_field").value =v * document.getElementById("text_field").value  ;

        }   
        if (operator == '/')
        {
        document.getElementById("text_field").value = v /  document.getElementById("text_field").value  ;

        }   
        }
    else {
         document.getElementById("text_field").value = document.getElementById("text_field").value + obj.value;
    }

    }






    </script>
```

Comment: A value is *always* a string, you have to parse the values to numbers to be able to add them up

Comment: how i can do it

Comment: Using parseFloat or parseInt, just look it up and you should be able to do it yourself

Comment: Can You Place Both HTML And JS In Code Snippet?

Comment: i am trying to put togather but can't

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

for example:

`parseInt(document.getElementById("text_field").value)`